# NodeJS parse csv websocket typeerror sending a row

Tags: node.js, websocket

I am having trouble sending over each row in a CSV file to my client program using websocket. It keep throw a type error "buffer.js:202
  throw new TypeError(kFromErrorMsg); TypeError: First argument must be a string, Buffer, ArrayBuffer, Array, or array-like object.
"

```
const csv = require('csv-parser');
const fs = require('fs');
const WebSocket = require('ws');

const wss = new WebSocket.Server({ port: 8001 });

wss.on('connection', function connection(ws) {
    ws.on('message', function incoming(message) {
        console.log('received: %s', message);
    });

    fs.createReadStream('SensorData_20191013_v8.csv')
    .pipe(csv())
    .on('data', (row) => {
        //data.push(row);
            //conn.sendText(row);
            ws.send(row);

        })

    .on('end', function () {
        console.log("done");
    })

    //ws.send('something');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to stringify the row if you are converting it to a JSON before sending over websockets.

```
ws.send(JSON.stringify(row));
```